# How to speed-up my code?

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

If possible, please help me speed-up the bootstrap code below.

```
sampleOne   <- function(x) sample(x, replace = TRUE)
sampleMany  <- function(x, n) replicate(n, sampleOne(x), simplify = FALSE)
listMeans <- function(x, n) lapply(sampleMany(x, n), mean)
bootData <- function(x,n) do.call(rbind, listMeans(x,n))
sampleSize <- 100000
numBoots <- 1000
# Left Skewed distribution # shape1 = a and shape2 = b
set.seed(400)
popSkewLeft <- rbeta(sampleSize, shape1 = 5, shape2 = 1)
skewLeftbootData <- bootData(popSkewLeft, numBoots)
(bootSd <- sd(skewLeftbootData) * sqrt(sampleSize))
```

I know that I can use the boot package but my objective here is to hone my skills in base R

Comment: The advantages (or not) of bootstrapping is not a programming question, but a statistics question. This is definitely off topic here, but might be on topic at crossvalidated.com.

Comment: Thank you, i will post this question on  crossvalidated.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics and belongs on CrossValidated.